# Support of + operator in a generic class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am newbie in C#. I need to create a generic class. There should be one constraint also : "client can implement by Int or Float class".
Contains a 'totalNums' method which will return total.

Generic Class

```
public class clsPrint<T>
{      

    public T totalNums(T num1, T num2)
    {
        T Total = num1 + num2;
        return Total;
    }        

}
```

Compile time error on "Num1 + Num2" : **Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'**.

Why I am getting this error and what will be the solution?

Comment: When writing generics, `T` is basically treated as `object` when you are writing the code. Therefore, `object + object` doesn't make any syntactic sense.

Comment: So, is there any other way to achieve it? @Abion47

Comment: Strictly speaking, there's a way using reflection and abstraction (see my duplicate comment), but it's pretty ugly. In general, I'd suggest not using generics at all for this, but rather use two different method overloads: one that takes `int` parameters, and one that takes `float` parameters.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I wanted to practice Generic class. So this idea came in mind.

Comment: Don't do that in the first place. If it can only be instantiated with int and float then it is not *generic*. Simply make two classes, one for int operations and one for float operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the type of `T` is not known until instantiation, there is no guarantee that the type `T` will support the `+` operator.

There's a workaround using `dynamic` operator: *(note: if you don't pass `+` supported operands then it WILL throw a runtime error.)*

```
public T totalNums(T num1, T num1)
        {
            dynamic dx = num1, dy = num1;
            return dx + dy;
        }
```

Comment: So, is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: Fine. Can I add Int, Float or string class as a constraint class?
Example : public class clsPrint<T> where T : String

Comment: @Mohit `int`, `float`, and `string` are sealed classes. You cannot use sealed classes as generic constraints.

Comment: Thank you @Abion47.

Comment: @Abion47: `int`, `float` and `string` are keywords. `int` denotes `System.Int32` and `float` denotes `System.Single` both of which are `structs`. Structs are `value types` and `value types` are sealed. Also `string` denotes the sealed class `System.String`.

Comment: You can also use your original code and attempt to cast the objects to a specific type (i.e. int.parse(t.ToString()) or Convert.ToDouble(t)) but you'll still get errors if they don't cast properly.

Comment: @user1895086 That approach completely defeats the purpose of using generics.